# Error in eclipse with ATG plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, atg

I do not know what caused this, but my ATG plug-in stopped working giving following error.

[image: ATG Eclipse plugin]

Comment: Is there a module called 'DeleteMe' in your ATG_ROOT dir that it's mentioning?

Comment: 'DeleteMe' is the sample project i created in new workspace to test if there is any issue with current workspace, this project is not even ATG project but Eclipse Dynamic project.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, perspective is set to ATG
- I think ATG root directory should also be correctly set, as there is no other error in ATG development tasks.

I noticed one thing later that one of the tab(out of 3) of plugin is not working but rest are working fine. That would be enough for me for now, so not worried about that 1 tab for now.

[image: ATG EClipse Response]]